# Main Category showing posts underneath

Tags: php, laravel

**PostController.php**

```
public function index($id) 
{
    $post = Post::where('post_id', $id)->first();

    $categories = DB::table('categories')->select('name AS category_name', 'slug AS category_slug', 'category_id AS cid')->get();

    return view('post', compact('post','categories'));
}
```

**post.blade.php**

```
<div class="accordion sticky-top" id="sideNavigation" style="top:55px">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <?php $posts_list = DB::table('posts')->join('categories', 'categories.category_id', 'posts.category_id')
            ->where('posts.category_id', $category->cid)
            ->get();
        ?>
        <h2 class="mb-0 border-bottom py-2 ">
            <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#{{$category->category_slug}}" aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="{{$category->category_slug}}">
                {{ $category->category_name}}
            </button>
        </h2>

        <div id="{{$category->category_slug}}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
             data-parent="#sideNavigation">
            <div class="card-body">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    @foreach($posts_list as $post_list)
                        <li><a href="{{ $post_list->post_id}}">{{$post_list->title}}</a></li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

The idea is so have this:

Category

- Post
- Post
- Post

Category 2

- Post
- Post

My current solution works but I can see this becoming a problem very quickly to maintain.

Comment: What's your question? If everything is working, how can we help?

Comment: Can the posts have multiple categories?

Comment: This is conceptually wrong in MVC terms to begin with, because you are making a database query in a place where it absolutely doesn’t belong, in the _view_.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add relationships to your models. [Documentation is here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

Providing its a one to many relationship you would do the following

In your Category model

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'category_id', 'category_id');
}
```

In your Post model

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Category', 'category_id', 'category_id');
}
```

Then you can clean up your view

```
<div class="accordion sticky-top" id="sideNavigation" style="top:55px">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
       <h2 class="mb-0 border-bottom py-2 ">
       <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{$category->category_slug}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="{{$category->category_slug}}">{{ $category->category_name}}</button>
       </h2>
       <div id="{{$category->category_slug}}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#sideNavigation">
           <div class="card-body">
               <ul class="list-unstyled">   
               @foreach($category->posts as $post)
                   <li><a href="{{ $post->post_id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></li>
               @endforeach
               </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
   @endforeach     
</div>
```

I would also think this line is not the best way of going about it, you will likely need a route applying

```
<a href="{{ $post->post_id}}">
```